# Can Google Script(deployed as web app) url be used as endpoint in alexa skill?

Tags: google-apps-script, alexa-skills-kit

[EDIT]: *The SSL handshake to endpoint Resource [https://xx.yyy.xxx.yy], Type [HTTP] failed. Please check that your java keystore is correctly configured.* This is the error I am getting.

I am trying to build my first alexa skill and I am trying to do it without using lambda. I was wondering if we could use google script url as endpoint for the alexa skill. I tried it but alexa says that the skill is unreachable and the google script is also not executed

Comment: Is your web app published as " Anyone including anonymous;Run as me"?

Comment: Yes, I have made sure that the publish configuration is correct. I have tried executing the webapp through incognito mode of chrome browser as well and it works

Comment: Seems something is wrong with your ssl certificates/java keystore?